# onclick counter = array.length not functioning

Tags: javascript, counter, alert, increment

I can't figure out why my counter isn't working. I feel like it should be since it will work on some different code on a wordpress site, but it is not working with this code if I open it from the .html file I'm testing. I'm not a coder so I'm sure my code looks in disarray, so go easy on me.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>JS Test</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Test Javascript</h1>
            <form id="form1">
                <fieldset id="java">
                    <legend>Form Append Test</legend>
                    <div id="tabelRow">
                    </div>
                    <div id="button">
                        <p><input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Click"></p>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function myFunction() {
                    var fs = document.getElementById("java");
                    var button = document.getElementById("button");
                    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
                    var newH = document.createElement("label");
                    var hText = document.createTextNode("Product");
                    var newP = document.createElement("select");
                    var options = [
                        {
                            "text"  :  "FHA",
                            "value" :  "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "text"  :  "USDA",
                            "value" :  "2"
                        },
                        {
                            "text"  :  "VA",
                            "value" :  "3"
                        },
                        {
                            "text"  :  "Convnetional",
                            "value" :  "4"
                        },
                        {
                            "text"  :  "Construction",
                            "value" :  "5"
                        },
                        {
                            "text"  :  "Chattel",
                            "value" :  "6"
                        },
                        {
                            "text"  :  "Fannie MAE HARP",
                            "value" :  "7"
                        }
                    ];
                    newH.appendChild(hText);
                    newDiv.className = "tablerow test";
                    newDiv.appendChild(newH);
                    newDiv.appendChild(newP);
                    var ol = options.length;
                    var counter = 0;

                    if (counter == ol) {
                        alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
                    }
                    else {
                        for(var i = 0; i < ol; i++) {
                            var proMenu = options[i];
                            newP.options.add( new Option(proMenu.text, proMenu.value));
                        }
                    fs.appendChild(newDiv);
                    fs.insertBefore(newDiv, button);
                    counter++;
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You set the counter to 0 every time the function is entered, so the condition will never be true unless `ol` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in your function `myFunction` you initialize `counter` to zero and then increment it once. But every time your function is called as a result of clicking the button, it is reinitialized to zero.

You probably want to put all your initialization logic outside of the function, and just make it responsible for doing the things you actually want done every click.

```js
var fs = document.getElementById("java");
var button = document.getElementById("button")
var options = [{
  "text": "FHA",
  "value": "1"
}, {
  "text": "USDA",
  "value": "2"
}, {
  "text": "VA",
  "value": "3"
}, {
  "text": "Convnetional",
  "value": "4"
}, {
  "text": "Construction",
  "value": "5"
}, {
  "text": "Chattel",
  "value": "6"
}, {
  "text": "Fannie MAE HARP",
  "value": "7"
}];
var ol = options.length;
var counter = 0;

function addOption() {
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  var newH = document.createElement("label");
  var hText = document.createTextNode("Product");
  var newP = document.createElement("select");
  newH.appendChild(hText);
  newDiv.className = "tablerow test";
  newDiv.appendChild(newH);
  newDiv.appendChild(newP);

  if (counter == ol) {
    alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < ol; i++) {
      var proMenu = options[i];
      newP.options.add(new Option(proMenu.text, proMenu.value));
    }
    fs.appendChild(newDiv);
    fs.insertBefore(newDiv, button);
    counter++;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JS Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Test Javascript</h1>
  <form id="form1">
    <fieldset id="java">
      <legend>Form Append Test</legend>
      <div id="tabelRow">
      </div>
      <div id="button">
        <p>
          <input type="button" onclick="addOption()" value="Click">
        </p>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Such a simple answer for something that baffled me for hours. Thanks all!

Answer (score 3):

It's because your `counter` variable is being reset to 0 each time the button is clicked.

Move `var counter= 0;` outside the function, and it works fine:

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mh7z7c0k/)